# Find minimum value from four columns and compare it with range in different column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which has below data:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4     col5       output          range           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-1      -1      -1      -1       -1                         99.9% - 100%
-1      -1      -1      -1       -1                         98% - 99.8%
87.8    78.6    95.2    98.2    94.7                        95% - 98.9%
100     100     100     100     100                         90% - 94.9%
90.4    86      96.6    73.2    95.5                        80% - 89.9%
92.9    88.9    93.1    100     100                         0% - 79.9%
85.7    80      82.2    100     100
85.7    80      82.2    100     100
98.3    100     97.9    100     94.4
```

Now I need to come up with a formula which can do below things:

- I need to figure out out minimum of `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5` and if that minimun is falling under any of those range mentioned in `Range` column, then I need to print that range in `output` column.
- But if `col1` has value `-1` then in `output` column I want to write "Fail". We will ignore point 1 above if `col1` has value `-1`.

So for example output will be:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4     col5       output          range           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-1      -1      -1      -1       -1          Fail           99.9% - 100%
-1      -1      -1      -1       -1          Fail           98% - 99.8%
87.8    78.6    95.2    98.2    94.7         0% - 79.9%     95% - 98.9%
100     100     100     100     100          99.9% - 100%   90% - 94.9%
90.4    86      96.6    73.2    95.5         0% - 79.9%     80% - 89.9%
92.9    88.9    93.1    100     100          80% - 89.9%    0% - 79.9%
85.7    80      82.2    100     100          80% - 89.9%
85.7    80      82.2    100     100          80% - 89.9%
98.3    100     97.9    100     94.4         90% - 94.9%
```

Is this possible to do by any chance in excel? It looks like pretty complex so I am kinda confuse on how to do this in excel automatically using some formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Columns K through N are a reference.

Formula for H2:

```
=MIN(B2:E2)
```

Formula for I2:

```
=IF(A2=-1,"z",IF(H2>$L$2,"a",IF(H2>$L$3,"b",IF(H2>$L$4,"c",IF(H2>$L$5,"d",IF(H2>$L$6,"e","f"))))))
```

Formula for F2:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,K:N,4,FALSE)
```

Drag 'em down and you're done.

[image]

Granted, you could accomplish this with fewer columns, but I've laid it out this way for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Order the ranges in ascending order, create a column of the lower bounds of the ranges and use LOOKUP function to find the appropriate range.

Comment: yeah I already created the column `col6` of lower bounds from `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5` but now I am confuse on how to use LOOKUP function here? can you provide an example or formula on how that would look like?

Comment: I don't have excel at this computer, so I can't check for typos and stuff, but it should look something like =IF(A2=-1;"fail";LOOKUP(MIN(B2:E2);G$2:G$7;H$2:H$7)